# How Do I Get Order Total Based on Counts and Groupings

Tags: sql, database, t-sql

I think this is best explained by providing my data - It is a bit long.

I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE #MemberTypes
(
    [Id]          INT           NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    [MemberType]  NVARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE #ChargeTypes
(
    [Id]            INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [ChargeType]    NVARCHAR (45) NOT NULL,
    [isAGroupRate]  bit           NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE #MemberTypeChargeType
(
    MemberTypeId   int NOT NULL,
    ChargeTypeId   int NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT [PK_#MemberTypeChargeType] 
        PRIMARY KEY ([MemberTypeId], [ChargeTypeId])
)

CREATE TABLE #ChargeRates
(
    [Id]           INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [ChargeTypeId] INT            NOT NULL,
    [EarlyBird]    BIT            DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    [FromCount]    SMALLINT       NOT NULL,
    [ToCount]      SMALLINT       NOT NULL,
    [RatePrice]    DECIMAL (6, 2) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_#ChargeRate_Id] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [UX_#ChargeType_EarlyBird_FromCount] 
        UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([ChargeTypeId] ASC, [EarlyBird] ASC, [FromCount] ASC)
);


INSERT INTO #MemberTypes(MemberType)
VALUES ('Regular'), ('Doctor')
    
INSERT INTO #ChargeTypes(ChargeType, [isAGroupRate])
VALUES ('Regular', 0), ('Service People', 0), ('Reciprocation', 1)

INSERT INTO #MemberTypeChargeType(MemberTypeId, ChargeTypeId)
VALUES (2, 2), (1, 1), (1, 3)
    
INSERT INTO #ChargeRates([ChargeTypeId],[EarlyBird],[FromCount],[ToCount],[RatePrice])
VALUES (3, 1, 10, 25, 65.00),
        (3, 0, 10, 25, 75.00),
        (3, 1, 26, 50, 35.00),
        (3, 0, 26, 50, 45.00),
        (3, 1, 51, 9999, 0.00),
        (3, 0, 51, 9999, 0.00),
        (1, 1, 1, 10, 6.00),
        (1, 1, 11, 9999, 3.00),
        (1, 0, 1, 10, 7.00),
        (1, 0, 11, 9999, 4.00),
        (2, 1, 1, 9999, 8.00),
        (2, 0, 1, 9999, 8.00)
        
--I then have another table 
CREATE TABLE #OrderItems 
(
    id              int IDENTITY(1,1),
    [OrderId]       int NOT NULL,
    RecipientId     int NOT NULL,
    Reciprocated    bit NOT NULL,
    MemberTypeId    INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_#OrderItem] 
        PRIMARY KEY ([OrderId], RecipientId)
);

--with data similar to this

INSERT INTO #OrderItems (OrderId, RecipientId, Reciprocated, MemberTypeId)
VALUES (129, 4, 0, 1),
        (129, 8, 0, 1),
        (129, 13, 0, 1),
        (129, 23, 0, 1),
        (129, 30, 0, 1),
        (129, 31, 0, 1),
        (129, 39, 0, 1),
        (129, 41, 0, 1),
        (129, 42, 0, 1),
        (129, 45, 0, 1),
        (129, 55, 0, 1),
        (129, 59, 0, 1),
        (129, 60, 1, 1),
        (129, 71, 0, 1),
        (129, 72, 0, 1),
        (129, 73, 0, 1),
        (129, 77, 0, 1),
        (129, 87, 0, 1),
        (129, 92, 0, 1),
        (129, 96, 0, 1),
        (129, 100, 0, 1),
        (129, 110, 0, 1),
        (129, 111, 0, 1),
        (129, 120, 0, 1),
        (129, 123, 0, 1),
        (129, 129, 0, 1),
        (129, 134, 0, 1),
        (129, 137, 1, 1 ),
        (129, 139, 0, 1),
        (129, 142, 1, 1),
        (129, 153, 0, 1),
        (129, 158, 0, 1),
        (129, 163, 0, 1),
        (129, 170, 0, 1),
        (129, 173, 0, 1),
        (129, 178, 1, 1),
        (129, 186, 0, 1),
        (129, 195, 0, 1),
        (129, 208, 0, 1),
        (129, 216, 0, 1),
        (129, 217, 0, 1),
        (129, 223, 0, 1),
        (129, 229, 0, 1),
        (129, 236, 0, 1),
        (129, 244, 0, 1),
        (129, 256, 0, 1),
        (129, 270, 0, 1),
        (129, 272, 1, 1),
        (129, 282, 0, 1),
        (129, 298, 0, 1),
        (129, 311, 0, 1),
        (129, 321, 0, 1),
        (129, 323, 0, 1),
        (129, 327, 0, 1),
        (129, 329, 0, 1),
        (129, 330, 0, 1),
        (129, 344, 1, 1),
        (129, 366, 0, 2),
        (129, 368, 0, 1),
        (129, 372, 0, 1),
        (129, 410, 0, 1),
        (129, 412, 0, 1),
        (129, 431, 0, 1),
        (129, 451, 0, 1),
        (129, 546, 0, 1),
        (129, 552, 0, 1),
        (129, 612, 1, 1),
        (129, 741, 0, 1),
        (129, 748, 0, 2),
        (129, 749, 1, 1),
        (129, 750, 1, 1),
        (129, 756, 1, 1),
        (129, 778, 0, 1),
        (129, 781, 1, 1),
        (129, 810, 0, 1),
        (129, 822, 1, 1),
        (129, 867, 0, 1),
        (129, 873, 0, 1),
        (129, 901, 0, 1),
        (129, 955, 0, 2),
        (129, 983, 0, 1),
        (129, 1034, 1, 1),
        (129, 1060, 0, 1)
```

The result I need is this:

| ChargeTypeId | FromCount | ToCount | ItemCount | Price | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 | 10 | 6.00 | 60 |
| 1 | 11 | 9999 | 57 | 3.00 | 171 |
| 2 | 1 | 9999 | 3 | 8.00 | 24 |
| 3 | 51 | 9999 | 67 | 0.00 | 0 |

In this result, I assume that the person who made the order was an EarlyBird and Chose to Reciprocate.

First, any Item #OrderItems that has Reciprocated = true needs to be ignored

In this case, there are 83 items - 13 of which are reciprocated. So we are working with 83 - 13, which is 70

#MemberTypeChargeType links the MemberTypeId with the ChargeTypeId with

67 Members are of type MemberId = 1  - The Charge Types applicable are 1 & 3

3 Members are of Type MemberId = 2 - The Charge Type applicable is 2

Charge type 1 has two levels. For the first 10, the charge is 6 per person(60), but for the next 57, it is 3 per person(171)

Charge Type 2 only has one level, and there are 3 people at 8 per person(24)

In table #ChargeTypes, there is a column called AGroupRate. When this is false, the charges are per person.

The tricky one is Charge type 3, as it is based on a group rate based on the total number of MemberTypeId = 1 or any other MemberTypeId linked to it.

In our case, we have a total of 67, and this fits into the slot where FromCount to ToCount is 51 to 9999, so the charge is 0

Is this possible in SQL - I am trying to avoid hard-coded values, but it is okay if there is more than one SQL query.

I need it in a stored procedure where I supply the order `@ID`, `@EarlyBird` and `@Reciprocate` as parameters.

My current method works, but I have hard-coded some of the values in the SQL, and I am trying to move away from that - I think it is possible, but my less elegant solution is working, so I am finding it hard to see the workaround.

## Edit

I have full control of the tables #MemberTypes, #ChargeTypes, #MemberTypeChargeType, #ChargeRates
So, if you think I should reconstruct them in a way that would make achieving my objective better, that would be an option.
The result should remain the same - and the ID values should also stay the same.

below is what I am doing - as you can see, it requires me to know what types there are, and I am using the tables just to store the values currently.
So the prices and ranges can change but not the types themselves

```
declare 
    @orderId        int = 129
    ,@orderYear     int = null
    ,@orderTotal    decimal(18,2) = null    
    ,@debug         bit = 1
    ,@earlyBird     bit = 1
    ,@reciprocate   bit = 1

    declare @regCount       int
            ,@docCount      int
            ,@totCount      int
            ,@regCost       decimal(18,2)
            ,@docCost       decimal(18,2)
            ,@recipCost     decimal(18,2)
            ,@totCost       decimal(18,2)

    select @regCount    = (select count(*) from #OrderItems o2 where o2.OrderId = @orderId and o2.MemberTypeId = 1 and o2.Reciprocated = 0)
        ,@docCount      = (select count(*) from #OrderItems o2 where o2.OrderId = @orderId and o2.MemberTypeId = 2)
        ,@totCount      = (select count(*) from #OrderItems o2 where o2.OrderId = @orderId and o2.Reciprocated = 0)

    if @debug = 1
    begin
        select
            @orderId        [@orderId]
            ,@regCount      [@regCount]
            ,@docCount      [@docCount]
            ,@totCount      [@totCount]
            ,@earlyBird     [@earlyBird]
            ,@reciprocate   [@reciprocate]
    end

    select 
         @regCost = sum(case when @regCount >= cr.FromCount and cr.ChargeTypeId = 1 then (case when cr.ToCount < @regCount then cr.ToCount else @regCount - (cr.FromCount -1) end) * cr.RatePrice else 0 end)   
        ,@docCost = sum(case when @docCount >= cr.FromCount and cr.ChargeTypeId = 2 then (case when cr.ToCount < @docCount then cr.ToCount else @docCount - (cr.FromCount -1) end) * cr.RatePrice else 0 end)   
        ,@recipCost = sum(case when @totCount > 0 and cr.ChargeTypeId = 3 and @reciprocate = 1 then case when @totCount between cr.FromCount and cr.ToCount then cr.RatePrice else 0 end else 0 end)                
    from #ChargeRates cr
    where   cr.EarlyBird    = @earlyBird

    if @debug = 1
         select @regCost 
                ,@docCost 
                ,@recipCost 

    set @totCost = @regCost + @docCost + @recipCost
    
    if @debug = 1
    begin
        select
            @regCost        [@regCost]
            ,@docCost       [@docCost]
            ,@recipCost     [@recipCost]
            ,@totCost       [@totCost]
    end

    select @totCost;
```

Comment: Please share your attempt

Comment: for `Charge type 3` what do you mean exactly by `it is based on a group rate based on the total number of MemberTypeId = 1 or any other MemberTypeId linked to it`?

Comment: For this case yes, it only looks at items where MemberTypeId = 1 - and charges a flat rate - as 67 is inside the range 51 to 9999, the charge is 0. On the other hand, if it was 50 or less they would be charged an extra 35.00

Comment: Please put the answer in an answer post, not as part of the question.

Comment: Thanks I just did that, was not sure how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the 2 different logic for `ChargeTypeId` `1,2` and `3`, I have split into 2 separate cte (`cte1` and `cte2`) and `union all` for the final result.

The different in the logic is at the `ON` condition when joining to `ChargeRates`

```
with cte
as
(
  select mtct.ChargeTypeId, 
         TotalCount = count(*)
  from   #OrderItems oi
         inner join #MemberTypeChargeType mtct on mtct.MemberTypeId = oi.MemberTypeId
  where Reciprocated  = 0
  group by mtct.ChargeTypeId
),
cte1 as
( -- ChargeType : 1, 2
  select c.ChargeTypeId, c.TotalCount, cr.Id, cr.FromCount, cr.ToCount, cr.RatePrice,
         i.ItemCount, 
         Total = cr.RatePrice * i.ItemCount
  from   cte c
         inner join #ChargeRates cr on  cr.ChargeTypeId = c.ChargeTypeId
                                    and cr.FromCount   <= c.TotalCount
         cross apply
         (
             select ItemCount = case when c.TotalCount >= cr.ToCount
                                     then cr.ToCount - cr.FromCount + 1
                                     else c.TotalCount - cr.FromCount + 1
                                     end
       ) i
  where  cr.EarlyBird = 1
  and    c.ChargeTypeId <> 3
),
cte2 as
( -- ChargeType : 3
  select c.ChargeTypeId, c.TotalCount, cr.Id, cr.FromCount, cr.ToCount, cr.RatePrice,
        i.ItemCount, 
        Total = cr.RatePrice * i.ItemCount
  from   cte c
         inner join #ChargeRates cr on  cr.ChargeTypeId = c.ChargeTypeId
                                    and cr.FromCount   <= c.TotalCount
                                    and cr.Tocount     >= c.TotalCount
         cross apply
         (
           select ItemCount = case when c.TotalCount >= cr.ToCount
                                   then cr.ToCount - cr.FromCount + 1
                                   else c.TotalCount - cr.FromCount + 1
                                   end
        ) i  
  where  cr.EarlyBird = 1
  and    c.ChargeTypeId = 3
)
select *
from   cte1
union all
select *
from   cte2
order by ChargeTypeId, FromCount
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/dicNlt-8)

Comment: Perfect, I just made a slight change to use the isAGroupRate in #ChargeTypes - please see my updated request.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Squirrel, this is the final code - actually, all his work - I just made the smallest change.

I just added using the column isAGroupRate in the #ChargeTypes table, instead of the ChargeTypeId.

```
;with cte
as
(
  select mtct.ChargeTypeId, 
         ct.isAGroupRate,
         TotalCount = count(*)
  from   #OrderItems oi
         inner join #MemberTypeChargeType mtct on mtct.MemberTypeId = oi.MemberTypeId
         left join #ChargeTypes ct on mtct.ChargeTypeId = ct.Id
  where Reciprocated  = 0
  group by mtct.ChargeTypeId, ct.isAGroupRate
),
cte1 as
( -- ChargeType : 1, 2
  select c.ChargeTypeId, c.TotalCount, cr.Id, cr.FromCount, cr.ToCount, cr.RatePrice,
         i.ItemCount, 
         Total = cr.RatePrice * i.ItemCount
  from   cte c
         inner join #ChargeRates cr on  cr.ChargeTypeId = c.ChargeTypeId
                                    and cr.FromCount   <= c.TotalCount
         cross apply
         (
             select ItemCount = case when c.TotalCount >= cr.ToCount
                                     then cr.ToCount - cr.FromCount + 1
                                     else c.TotalCount - cr.FromCount + 1
                                     end
       ) i
  where  cr.EarlyBird = 1
  and    c.isAGroupRate = 0
),
cte2 as
( -- ChargeType : 3
  select c.ChargeTypeId, c.TotalCount, cr.Id, cr.FromCount, cr.ToCount, cr.RatePrice,
        i.ItemCount, 
        Total = cr.RatePrice * i.ItemCount
  from   cte c
         inner join #ChargeRates cr on  cr.ChargeTypeId = c.ChargeTypeId
                                    and cr.FromCount   <= c.TotalCount
                                    and cr.Tocount     >= c.TotalCount
         cross apply
         (
           select ItemCount = case when c.TotalCount >= cr.ToCount
                                   then cr.ToCount - cr.FromCount + 1
                                   else c.TotalCount - cr.FromCount + 1
                                   end
        ) i  
  where  cr.EarlyBird = 1
  and    c.isAGroupRate = 1
)
select *
from   cte1
union all
select *
from   cte2
order by ChargeTypeId, FromCount
```